# Linux Mint - touchpad doesn't working after wake up

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, touchpad

I've installed Linux Mint with Cinnamon environment on my Asus X302LA. Unfortunately, touchpad doesn't work after waking up from sleep. Does anyone knows a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. However I noticed that by disabling and enabling back the touchpad it works again.

The  workaround I use is opening a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type

```
xinput disable XX
xinput enable XX
```

where `xx` is the touchpad's device id

`xinput` without any arguments should list all your devices and their respective ids.

Comment: "xinput disable XX" and "xinput enable XX" are separate commands obviously :-)

Comment: Have a look at the source of your answer now to learn how the formatting works.